# Consume Azure Authenticated .net core API with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, webapi

I'm trying to invoke an azure ad authenticated .net core api with powershell script. Can someone help me with the powershell script? I have already created an app registration for the api in azure active directory.

Comment: Hi @Dev, Are you authenticating with .net or PowerShell?what is the interaction between both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exposed the api protected by Azure, created an application registration for the api, and then used the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain the token:

[image]

script:

```
$clientID = 'a13b414b-93b3-4aae-bb68-6a40ffxxxxxx'
$secretKey = '4.Yi4qwn_rqe7BK3F6Nfz.c0A7pTxxxxxx'
$tenantID = 'e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2xxxxxx'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretKey -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientID,$password)
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant $tenantID

$authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + $tenantID + "/oauth2/v2.0/token/"
$body = @{
   "scope" = "api://a13b414b-93b3-4aae-bb68-6a40ffxxxxxx/.default";
   "grant_type" = "client_credentials";
   "client_id" = $ClientID
   "client_secret" = $secretKey
}

Write-Output "Getting Authentication-Token" 
$adlsToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $authUrl –Method POST -Body $body
Write-Output $adlsToken
```

Comment: This script helped. Thanks!